# Sum of "positive" numbers

Tags: real-numbers, square-numbers

Given this definition of a positive real number: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},x\geq 0:\Leftrightarrow\exists y\in\mathbb{R},x=y^2$$
how to prove that the sum of two positive numbers is a positive number? It is fairly easy for the product, but not so for the sum.

EDIT: To add a context to this, let's say we define real numbers as the completion of rationals (but I'm not sure whether it needs an order to be defined on the rationals). Then, I'd like to define positivity on real numbers in order to create a total order with $x\geq y$ iff $x-y\geq 0$.

Comment: Do you mean “... the sum of two positive numbers is a *positive* number”?

Comment: Assume $a>b>0$. Then there are $x,y$ such that $a=x^2$ and $b=y^2$. Then $(a+b)^{1/2}=x(1+y^2/x^2)^{1/2}=x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}(y/x)^k$.  The completeness (or which ever axiom you have replacing it) tells you that $x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}(y/x)^k$ is a real number. Its square is $a+b$.

Comment: Normally o prove that the sum of positive numbers is positive one doesn't need to do this. For example, if the real numbers were defined as Dedekind cuts of the rationals, then you only need to take two rationals in them that are larger than zero and add them. Since the sum is larger than zero, the sum of the Dedekind cuts is also larger than zero. The argument above is assuming that you wanted to pass through the implication that the sum is a square.

Comment: What axioms do you have to work with? (This context would be especially helpful because common definitions of the real numbers often have the conclusion you want included as an axiom)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I edited my question

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Actually, this partially answers my question, because I haven't defined $a>b$ (yet I could say $a-b>0$ and $x>0$ iff $x\geq0$ and $x\neq0$) and the convergence of this power series is yet to prove. Also, I don't want to use Dedekind cuts as they need to define first an order on the rationals.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Please look at my edit (currenty in progress) for details concerning the context.

Comment: What kind of completion is involved in your construction of $\mathbb{R}$? This is very crucial because we must lift the ordering of $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ along with the construction and then show that this coincide with your definition. Without ordering, we have counter-examples such as $p$-adic fields $\mathbb{Q}_p$, which are Cauchy-completions of $\mathbb{Q}$ under different types of "absolute values". There, it turns out that the positivity, defined as in OP, needs not be preserved under addition. For instance, in $\mathbb{Q}_3$, $1=1^2$ is "positive" but $2=1+1$ is not positive.

Comment: @Maxence1402 Those missing details you can complete.

Comment: @SangchulLee I consider the real numbers as equivalence classes of rational Cauchy sequences, but it needs an order to be defined first. My conclusion is that real numbers can't exist without an order defined first on the rationals.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't have the whole answer of the edit, but here's how you could show the first part.

If we define the field $\Bbb R$ so that it is totally ordered : [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), then this means, among other things, that

$$ \forall x,y,z \in \Bbb R, \; x \le y \implies x+z \le y+z  \qquad (1) $$

$$ \forall a,b,c \in \Bbb R, \; a \le b \; and \; b \le c\implies a \le c \qquad (2) $$

In this case, if we let $ x=0 $ and $ y, z $ be positive real numbers, we get by $(1)$ :

$$ 0 \le y \implies 0+z \le y+z $$

But $0+z=z \; and \; 0 \le z $, therefore we get by $(2)$ :

$$0 \le y+z $$

Therefore the sum of two positive numbers is a positive number.

EDIT :

Alright, so here is a more "geometrical" way I'm trying to give to prove that the sum of two positive real numbers is a positive real number.
First, we'll assume that the product of two real numbers with the same sign is a positive real number.

Let $a,b \in \Bbb R$ so that $x=a^2$ and $y=b^2$ are positive real numbers (by  definition).

Let's now consider a right triangle $ABC$ where $AC$ is the length of the hypothenus and so that $AB=x, BC=y$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem, we have : $AC^2=AB^2+BC^2=x^2+y^2$.

The fact that $x,y \ge0 $ is not a problem, because $(-w)^2=w^2 \quad \forall \ w \in \Bbb R $.

From now on, if we let $X=x^2, Y=y^2$ and $Z=AC^2$, we get that :

$ \forall \ X,Y \ge 0, \exists \ Z \ge  0 $ so that $X+Y=Z$.

Therefore the sum of two positive real numbers is a positive real number.

Comment: Actually no, and you're using the result in your proof. The point is that I haven't defined yet an order on real numbers. Also, being a total order does not imply that it is compatible with operations. I can define a total lexicographical order on complex numbers but it won't be compatible with operations.